# Making a website responsive with different sections of html (as well as media queries)

Tags: html, device, responsive

I'm making an online portfolio, and my menu, which consists of 3 flip card images, needs to be able to work on touch screen devices. Since I don't want to change anything about the desktop menu, I was thinking of creating a completely new menu for mobile devices, which would mean discarding a section of my html code and inserting a new section.

I'm not sure how best to do this - for example, is it possible to create different index pages for different device sizes? Every time I try and search the answer to this I only find results about css media queries, which I'm using as well, but in this case it's the content I want to change. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Erin.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: As an alternative to Bootstrap, the CSS3 `flexbox` module is very powerful for styling dynamic presentation. (Arguably even more powerful than Bootstrap).

In your question can you include an image showing what the flipcard menu looks like and then a second image showing how you envisage the touchscreen menu?

Answer (score 1):

Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). Its a little bit of effort to learn this but it will be a asset for the lifetime. You will get lot of construct in it to make any webpage work on all the screens simultaneously.

Edit:

If you dont want to use bootstrap use the following media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .in-small-devices {
        display: block;
    }

    .in-large-devices{
        display: none
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .in-small-devices {
        display: none;
    }

    .in-large-devices{
        display: block
    }
}
```

Then apply it to the two divs that you want to show alternatively

```
<div class="in-small-devices"></div>
<div class="in-large-devices"></div>
```

Comment: Great tip, thanks! Will definitely consider bootstrap for my next project (have used it sparingly in the past), but in the meantime i'm hoping to find a pure html answer as I've already put a lot of work into it...

Comment: You can use different index files if you are using any kind of MVC framework. In the controller you can check which browser you are getting request from and then render the different view for different browser.

I have edited my answer for a simple media query solution. This also might work in your case.

Comment: Ooh yes I hadn't thought of the display: none property and using both divs in the same html file, this could work quite well, will let you know, many thanks!

Comment: Don't forget `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your HTML

Comment: Hi Tejaswi, the display:none idea worked like a charm ;) Thanks!
But when I put the meta viewport in the html, the whole website only covers half the width of my mobile - any idea why?

Comment: I should reiterate, it's the backgrounds that are less than half of the screen size...

Comment: Ah ok, I started giving things a min-width instead of a width:100%, that seemed to do the trick... however for a media query of 320-480px i had to give a min-width of 800px for it to fill the device screen, which i found a bit odd, but it works so I won't knock it for now...

Comment: @Erin: In both the classes you can not only use the display property but any property you want. You may also add one or more class that controls your background in the small devices media query block so it can rewrite the background in small devices. Its very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap Grid classes you can define the width of a div on different screen (xs, sm, ...) sizes. For example you can hide whole codeblocks and display other html when on specific screen sizes.

```
<div class="visible-lg"></div> (visible on large screens)
<div class="hidden-xs"></div> (hidden on extra-small screens)

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"></div>
```

(at default 12 units are one row. This div will take 6 units space on small screens, but only 3 on large screens. This means 2 divs fit in row on small screens, but 4 divs on large screens)

take a closer look:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid